# Авторский текст внутри речи персонажа при множестве разных реплик

Tags: прямая-речь

> «Так вы и в Индии, наверное, бывали?» – «Да, – ответил эксперт, – я
>   часто бывал там на юге… как там это?..» **– Я вскинула голову. –** «На
>   Шри Ланке!» – убедительно выкрикнул он. Вот тогда я совсем изумилась.
>   Нормальный такой эксперт! Две страны перепутал.

Спереди и сзади ещё закавыченные вопросы от разных говорильщиков.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

В качестве возможного варианта:

«Так вы и в Индии, наверное, бывали?» – «Да, – ответил эксперт, – я часто бывал там на юге… как там это?..  **Я вскинула голову.**  «На Шри Ланке!» – убедительно выкрикнул он. **Вот тогда я совсем изумилась. Нормальный такой эксперт! Две страны перепутал.**

Тире (в соответствии с обычной практикой письма) выделяются действия говорящего персонажа, например у Тургенева:— Да, да, ужинать давайте, ужинать поскорее. — **Николай Петрович без всякой видимой причины потопал ногами.** — Вот кстати и Прокофьич.

В нашем случае это авторский тест, как и в конце абзаца.

Comment: А после "как там это?.." кавычка закрывается? Иначе сольётся в авторской речью.

Comment: Ну да, закрывается. Просто одна из кавычек потерялась.